# How can I yield in a recursively generated sequence

Tags: kotlin

I have a function generating values. It does so by recursively calling itself, and whenever the base case is reached, a value is emitted. This is just a toy example, the real one is much more complicated, and thus harder to transform to something non-recursive.

I would like to do this as a sequence. But doing this won't compile on the line I yield, with the message

> Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

Here's the attempt:

```
fun test1() = sequence {
    fun a(i: Int) {
        if (i > 4) {
            yield(i) // <- fails to compile
        } else {
            a(i + 1)
            a(i + 2)
            a(i + 3)
        }
    }
    a(1)
}
```

If I try to add the `suspend` keyword to function `a`, I instead get the error

> Restricted suspending functions can only invoke member or extension suspending functions on their restricted coroutine scope

I can make it work, by instead returning all the values and doing a yieldAll. The problem with this, however, is that it needs to do the whole computation and hold all the results in memory before the sequence can be used. For my case, this won't work as I'd run out of memory, or may even have an almost infinite amount of results where I only want to take a few.

So this works, but is not optimal

```
fun test2() = sequence {
    fun a(i: Int): List<Int> {
        if (i > 4) {
            return listOf(i)
        } else {
            return listOf(
                a(i + 1),
                a(i + 2),
                a(i + 3)
            ).flatten()
        }
    }
    yieldAll(a(1))
}
```

Any ideas on how to combine sequences with a recursive function, allowing me to yield values without pre-computing and allocating memory for all of them?

Comment: sequence belongs __into__ fun a(), then you can yield value by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the inner function a suspend function that is an extension of SequenceScope. The Sequence builder uses a special kind of coroutine that's limited to only calling suspend function extensions of SequenceScope. Presumably this is because Sequences are intended to be used only as synchronous, non-suspending iterables. Since `yield()` is one of these SequenceScope suspend functions, you have to make your function also a suspend extension function.

```
fun test1() = sequence {
    suspend fun SequenceScope<Int>.a(i: Int) {
        if (i > 4) {
            yield(i)
        } else {
            a(i + 1)
            a(i + 2)
            a(i + 3)
        }
    }
    a(1)
}
```

Comment: I haven't measured how heavy it is to be doing this recursively in a coroutine.

Comment: Tested on my algorithm with a huge input, did thousands runs of each to get the jit going. Not a scientific measurement, but anyways: Original recursive algorithm building a single huge list of outputs, used ~60ms on average. Sweeper's approach ~115ms, and yours ~90ms. But the biggest difference is that with the sequences it's easier to only hold one result in memory at a time, so I actually saves gigabytes of ram. So this worked quite nicely, will keep it in the toolbelt.

Answer (score 5):

How about making `a` return a lazy `Sequence`?

```
fun a(i: Int): Sequence<Int> =
    sequence {
        if (i > 4) {
            // println("yielding $i")
            yield(i)
        } else {
            yieldAll(a(i + 1)) // this yieldAll is lazy
            yieldAll(a(i + 2))
            yieldAll(a(i + 3))
        }
    }

fun test1() = a(1)
```

If you uncomment the `println`, and loop over the sequence, you will see that it is indeed lazy:

```
for (i in test1()) {
    println("printing $i")
}
```

Output:

```
yielding 5
printing 5
yielding 6
printing 6
yielding 7
printing 7
yielding 5
printing 5
yielding 6
printing 6
yielding 5
printing 5
yielding 6
printing 6
yielding 7
printing 7
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried making a having the sequence at first, but it didn't work. But yielding all on the recursive calls did the trick. So your way works!
Not very fast, though.. About ~5x slower than not doing it with a sequence, maybe it becomes too many nested sequences it has to create?

Comment: @Matsemann Yes. Too much laziness can potentially slow you down too. It also needs to “remember” what is unevaluated, so the memory usage isn’t necessarily lower than strict evaluation. There *might* be a faster way to write this with some cool coroutine tricks, since I’m not familiar with those. I suggest that you wait a bit longer and if there are no more answers, post a new question about your actual scenario. There might be another way to improve the performance, instead of laziness, or you don’t actually need recursion.

Comment: I already have other implementations of my code that works fine, so that's not an issue. I just wanted to see if using sequences could allow me to express it in a nicer way :)

Comment: Update, I had a small bug when converting the algorithm to nested sequences. So it's actually a bit faster than I initially reported. But a bit easier to shoot oneself in the foot with this approach compared to the other, since the returns had to be scoped correctly, and have to remember to yield all all the correct places.